# How to shared folder two groups

Tags: server, permissions, samba

I am completely new to Ubuntu, so I would ask for help.
I have two groups: P1 and P2. And I have a public folder called "PUBLIC-SHARED".
I want the members of the two groups to see only this "PUBLIC-SHARED" folder. Plus, everyone can only delete their own files, others can’t.

I'm trying it is:

```
[PUBLIC-SHARED]
  inherit owner = yes
  inherit permissions = yes
  comment = shared folder but not public
  guest ok = no
  path = /SHARED-FILES/PUBLIC-SHARED
  valid users = @P1, @P2
  read only = no
  force group = P1, P2
  browseable = yes
  create mask = 1777
  directory mask = 1777
```

But i think it is not working.